# Bleak can't find Arduino Nano 33 BLE

Tags: python, windows, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, arduino-nano

I want to read gyroscope and acceleration values from an Arduino Nano 33 BLE board by using Bleak on a Windows OS. The code to make the discovery is the default Bleak code (see [here](https://github.com/hbldh/bleak/blob/develop/examples/discover.py)). On Arduino I use a code similar to this [one](https://rootsaid.com/arduino-ble-example/), except that I work with the gyroscope and the accelerometer.

Using the Android nRF Connect application I can view the device and the characteristic. Using Bleak instead I can't see any device.

Is it possible to have a problem with permissions on Windows?
I tried to connect it via Bluetooth to the pc first, but Windows 10 says: try to connect your device again. But the Arduino sketch sees the connection attempt as a Central BLE device connecting, in fact he enters the while loop and starts sending data.
How to solve it?

Comment: Could you share your full code for the windows side please? Did you change anything of the example code?

Comment: @M.Kotzjan right now I am using the bleak default code to test it, without changing anything.